# Multi-condition count: pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have some trouble to complete a basic exercise with pandas.
Below, the given dataframe:

```
model   serial   failure
  A       23        0
  B       12        1
  A       14        1
  A       12        0
  B       23        1
  C       34        1
  C       11        1
```

I need to return a new dataframe with the columns: model,failures_count,failures_ratio.

My logic appears to be false and I do not get why it is:

```
def failure_per_model(self):
    models = list(self.data.model.unique())
    table = []
    for model in models:
        model_count = self.data[self.data['model'] == model].shape[0]
        failures_count = sum(self.data['failure'][self.data['model'] == model])           
        failures_ratio = failures_count / model_count
        table.append([model, failures_count, failures_ratio])
    return pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['model', 'failures_count', 'failures_ratio'])
```

I can actually do it in many ways but is anyone able to explain why it is bad practice here?

Thanks

Comment: I think better is use very nice implemented `groupby` with `agg` function. But if need some special case, then is necessary use cusom, because no such special function in pandas.

Comment: True thanks, I tend to omit the implemented function but I admit it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `aggregate` by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) - `sum` and `mean`:

```
print (data.groupby('model')['failure']
           .agg({'failures_count': 'sum', 'failures_ratio': 'mean'})
           .reset_index())
  model  failures_ratio  failures_count
0     A        0.333333               1
1     B        1.000000               2
2     C        1.000000               2
```

---

```
print (data.groupby('model', as_index=False)['failure']
           .agg({'failures_count': 'sum', 'failures_ratio': 'mean'}))

  model  failures_ratio  failures_count
0     A        0.333333               1
1     B        1.000000               2
2     C        1.000000               2
```

Comment: Thank you, I'd never use groupby before and should admit it is cleaner!

Comment: @Spikist feel free to up vote the answer as well.  It's appreciated.

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you.

Comment: @piRSquared 
Actually I've just reached the minimum number of points to do it hehe!
Probably with my last message to jezrael, it's done now.

Comment: @Spikist Actually, I saw that you had 10 points... I upvoted your question so that you'd have 15... then I asked you to upvote :-)